# How do you solve any partial differential equation using equivalent circuits? How is this possible?

Tags: electric-circuits, computational-physics, differential-equations, electronics, electrical-engineering

Here's the quote from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Kron) wiki:

> In 1945 Kron suggested an approach to Schrödinger's equation with networks. The same year he used equivalent circuits to solve differential equations.

So I've been looking into free online sources to see how this is done and have found none. So if anyone can either explain theory behind this or give a good free resource, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Heck, you can solve differential equations using mechanical systems (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_analyser). Doing similar things with electronic components is straightforward.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: https://chalkdustmagazine.com/features/analogue-computing-fun-differential-equations/ or https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/ece486/sp2020/laboratory/docs/lab1/analog_computer_manual.pdf came up early in a Google search on 'analog electronics differential equations'. Analog computers have a long history.

Comment: Thanks but those are sources showing how to solve ORDINARY differential equations. I m referring specifically to PARTIAL diff eqs.

Comment: And a Google search on "analog electronics partial differential equations" yields many hits as well...

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the ascendency of digital computation, *analog computers* were built for the express purpose of solving big differential equations. You implemented the equation through the use of resistors, inductors, capacitors, op amps and feedback loops. Do a search on analog computation for the details.

Comment: OP's question is, "How do circuits solve DiffEqs? Or provide a reference?" and your answer is "They do. Search online." Consider actually answering the question or deleting this non-answer outright.

Comment: This is a very good answer. " Do a search on analog computation for the details" will provide all the details --  no need to provide them here.  Analog computers solve differential equations including non linear ones.

Comment: @KyleKanos, please give me a break here. Although I myself programmed analog computers (Systron-Donners) in 1975,  the wikipedia entry on analog computers does a much better job than I can today on explaining all the ins & outs in the field. From the nature of your responses to my posts here I get the general impression that you and I got off on the wrong foot, shall we start over? Best regards, Niels

Comment: Are you really now claiming that you are entirely incapable of copying sections of a website and adding a link for users' convenience? Give me the break, please. As for wrong foot, I have zero opinion of you. I don't know who you are IRL and don't really care. I care that someone with >5k rep posts bad answers and would prefer *that* part fixed.

Comment: Perhaps if you *did* know who I am IRL we could communicate better. Wanna try?